# How can I read this fortran binary file in R

Tags: r, file, binary, fortran

Can somebody tell me what format this file is and how I can read it in R?  I am told that it can be read in Fortran, but I don't have a Fortran compiler.[image: binary file]

I have attempted to figure it out with the commands read.fortran() and read.fwf , and readBin(), but no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the file supposed to contain? Just address it to the limits of your knowledge. At least report what the file extension is.

Comment: More context would help. Like the file name and what you believe it contains.

Comment: I remember some old convention where Fortran-binary has some funky hidden bytes at the header and it is assumed they get skipped. I will try to find the reference

Answer (score 3):

The pattern makes this look like 4-byte entities (note the repeating occurrence of the sequence `00 42`).  I would guess float values.

Reproducing the first 6 values of your file into `test.dat` gives this:

```
0000000 f0 61 08 00 00 00 00 00 e4 db 00 42 85 e1 00 42
0000020 fc df 00 42 87 de 00 42
0000030
```

These are read into R with `readBin` by specifying the size:

```
readBin("test.dat", what=double(), size=4, n=6)
## [1] 7.698173e-40 0.000000e+00 3.221474e+01 3.222023e+01 3.221873e+01 3.221731e+01
```

These look reasonable, so I would assume that my guess of 4-byte float is correct.  I'm working on a little-endian (Intel) machine.  If yours is big-endian,  you'll need to specify `endian='little'` to achieve the same results.

R agrees with my C compiler about these values, so it is indeed reading little-endian IEEE 4-byte floats with the above expression.

Comment: The first one looks like a bit of a header though. Maybe its a 0x61 by 0x8 array of floats? The 'file' command doesn't recognise it on my system however. I can only add to the plea for context and/or the file itself!

Comment: @RafaelResendiz Perhaps you can ask a new question that is better formed than this one so it will not be closed, then answer it yourself.